# Adding a CADisplayLink to Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-loop, cadisplaylink

I have Cocos2D in my app and I use it as the game engine for my game. At this point I need to have a game loop fire at the rate the screen refreshes. So this leads me to think that I need to use CADisplayLink. So how would I implement CADisplayLink so that my game loop which will consist of Cocos2D will be called at the rate of the screen refreshing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2D has the CADisplayLink object already integrated. In fact, it will be using [CCDirectorDisplayLink](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_director_display_link.html) by default unless you have specified a different director type.

Check your project's AppDelegate class, in particular the didFinishLaunching… method.